# Make python script executable in WSL Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

maybe you can help me with my problem...
I'm trying to make a python script executable on Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL. 
I created a folder where my python scripts are saved `/home/<user>/Python_scripts`.
Second, I try to link the folder using the file `.pythonrc`

```
#.pythonrc file
import sys
import os
sys.path.append('/home/<user>/Python_scripts/')
print ('Scripts loaded')
#end .pythonrc file
```

Third, i add to my `.bashrc` the next line in order to relate `.pythonrc` file:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc
```

Finally `source .bashrc`
But the scripts are never loaded, i can't find the scripts executable.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, or some other version? There is no 18.06.

Comment: Yes sorry, typing error.... the version of ubuntu is 18.04

Comment: 1) Did you make your script executable with `chmod +x /home/<user>/Python_scripts/myscript.py` ? 2) Does your script have, as its first line, `#!/usr/local/bin/python` (or wherever Python itself is installed to) ? Please click [edit] and advise if you did those, or not. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].